# Apache POI - DOCX - Is there any chance to iterate through XWPFStyles?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

Have read docx using Apache POI (5.2.5) and want to enumerate all styles (not only the used styles) in an MS WORD docx.

```
XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();
```

OK, got styles. I also can output the number of styles (79 in my case):

```
System.out.println("Number of styles: "+styles.getNumberOfStyles());
```

OK, got number of styles. Is there any chance to get an array, a list or anything else that I could use to "walk" through all styles?
Thanks in advance.

I have read tons of Apache POI documentation but did not find any 'keep it simple and stupid' solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apache POI is open source, you can have a look into the source of  [XWPFStyles.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_5/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFStyles.java?view=markup). There you find a `private final List<XWPFStyle>`. This get used to get the number of styles:

```
public int getNumberOfStyles() {
    return listStyle.size();
}
```

However, there is no method that iterates through this list.

So only possibility I see is using reflection:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import java.util.List;

public class XWPFGetStyles {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  try ( 
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx");
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in); 
      ) {         
   XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();
   System.out.println(styles.getNumberOfStyles());
   
   // use reflection to get internally List<XWPFStyle> listStyle
   java.lang.reflect.Field _listStyle  = XWPFStyles.class.getDeclaredField("listStyle");
   _listStyle.setAccessible(true);
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   List<XWPFStyle> listStyle = (List<XWPFStyle>)_listStyle.get(styles);
   
   for (XWPFStyle style : listStyle) {
    System.out.println(style);
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();  
  }
  
 }
  
}
```